# jqplot set default value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

In my code, I want to set y-axis '0' when i didn't put the value in var line1.
Now I didn't put information about ['2013-01-25 11:23am'].

In this case, I want to set y-asix value to 0. No, it didn't work like that.

How can I do?

```
function Drawchart() {

    this.showChart = function() {
        $(document).ready(
                function() {

                    var line1 = [ [ '2013-01-25 11:20am', 20 ],
                            [ '2013-01-25 11:35AM', 30 ],
                            [ '2013-01-25 11:36AM', 7 ],
                            [ '2013-01-25 11:37AM', 3 ],
                            [ '2013-01-25 11:38AM', 1 ],
                            [ '2013-01-25 11:39AM', 2 ] ];
                    var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart', [ line1 ], {
                        title : 'Customized Date Axis',
                        gridPadding : {
                            right : 35
                        },
                        axes : {
                            xaxis : {
                                renderer : $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                                pad : 0,
                                tickOptions : {
                                    angle : -90,
                                    fontSize : "5pt",
                                    formatString : '%I:%M%p '
                                },
                                min : '11:00 AM',
                                tickInterval : '1 minute'
                            },
                            yaxis : {

                                min : 0
                            }

                        },
                        series : [ {
                            lineWidth : 4,
                            color : '#000000',
                            markerOptions : {
                                style : 'square'
                            }
                        } ]
                    });
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: How does jqplot know how many point must be draw? Are the points dynamic? In that case you could create the array dynamically and put a default value if there is not a value for certain date..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't because JQPlot need to know which points must be drawn in the serie.

You need to set your `0` points manualy like this : `['2013-01-25 11:23am',0]` and include them into the array.

```
   var line1=[['2013-01-25 11:20am',20],['2013-01-25 11:23am',0],['2013-01-25 11:35AM',30],['2013-01-25 11:36AM',7],['2013-01-25 11:37AM',3],['2013-01-25 11:38AM',1],['2013-01-25 11:39AM',2]];
```

Comment: I mean, even though I don't set 0, can't I have a default value '0' about every y-axis?  for example, if there are 10 points, and I set just 3 points values, then I want 7 points have '0' as a default. How can I?

Comment: You can't because JQPlot draws only the points that you provide.

Answer (score 0):

Are those 0s actual data points? if so then you should build your `line1` with that data or augment it outside of jqplot.

Perhaps also what might help you is a [canvas overlay](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/canvas-overlay.html)

```
$.jqplot('chart', [ line1 ], { 
    ...
    canvasOverlay: {
        show: true,
        objects: [
            {horizontalLine: {
                name: '',
                y: 0,
                lineWidth: 3,
                xOffset: 0,
                color: 'rgb(89, 198, 154)',
                shadow: false
            }}
        ]
    }  // end canvasOverlay
}); // end jqplot
```